# How to pass onClickListener as method parameter

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have method in ActionBar (Base) class that I want to call inside my fragment:

```
public void setOnBackButtonClickListener(OnClickListener onBackButtonClickListener) {
    this.onBackButtonClickListener = onBackButtonClickListener;
}
```

I am using ButterKnife, and I want to call that method inside my Fragment:

```
@Bind(R.id.action_bar) ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    actionBar.setOnBackButtonClickListener();    
}
```

How to pass onClickListener as parameter inside my method setOnBackButtonClickListener()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correctly you want to call method when you click the back button !!
you can just use Toolbar  instead of actionBar and call your method inside toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener
and in your case you are using an ActionBar,  then you can just tell Android to use the Toolbar as the ActionBar like so:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mtoolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And show home button to

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

. You can now use that in Fragments that are attached to ActionBarActivities you can use it like this:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

if you want to custom back arrow on a Toolbar :

```
mActionBar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back));
```

now you can call your methode :

```
mActionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //What to do on back clicked
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to create object of OnClickListener and then pass it as parameter to setOnBackButtonClickListener method.